# How accurate are times given for when questions/answers are posted?

Tags: support

In https://askubuntu.com/questions/431194/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-12-04-to-ubuntu-13-04, the question is at `2014-03-08 06:44:30Z` and the answer is at `2014-03-08 06:46:25Z`.

My question: how reliable are those times? If accurate, in this case it shows very fast typing or just clumsy rep rigging.

Comment: Looks clumsy to me.

Comment: so that the user raju is blocked.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, It's a crappy answer, IMO. But there's a lot of fake stuff going on. Is "rep" so important? Do people put it in their CVs? I think the answerer should be examined for other "irregular" activity.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. And yes, those times are very accurate.

Comment: @DKBose Rep can be part of a cv indeed. For a sys admin, for instance.